# getting Crystal Report error in client machine

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oracle, crystal-reports

I developed a desktop application in C# 4.0 with Oracle 11g & used Crystal report for VS 2010

it executing & running fine in developement machine & i created a setup file

In client system i installed oracle client and setup file of my application

able to use the application well until i generate any crystal report ..1st it display the below screen shot

[image]

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

2nd even if i click continue its asking me server username & password like below

[image]

```
private void VisitorIDReportWindow_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.CON.State.Equals(System.Data.ConnectionState.Open))
        {
            CON.Close();
        }
        CON.Open();

        DataTable DTB;
        string query1 = "Select * from VMS_VISITOR where PASSNUMBER ='" + VisitorCreationWindow.PNBR + "'";

        using (OLCMND1 = new OracleCommand(query1, CON))
        {
            using (OADAP1 = new OracleDataAdapter(OLCMND1))
            {
                DTB = new DataTable();
                OADAP1.Fill(DTB);
            }
        }

        RDT = new ReportDocument();
        string reportpath = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.Substring(0,System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.Substring(0,System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath.LastIndexOf("\\")).LastIndexOf("\\"));
        reportpath += @"\VisitorIDReport.rpt";   //string reportpath = "D:\\Visitor Management System\\Visitor Management System\\VisitorIDReport.rpt";
        RDT.Load(reportpath);

        ConnectionInfo connectioninfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        connectioninfo.DatabaseName = "ORCL";
        connectioninfo.UserID = "itapps";
        connectioninfo.Password = "it123";

        Logindetailforreport(connectioninfo,RDT);
        VisitorIDCrystalReportViewer.ReportSource = RDT;

        RDT.SetDataSource(DTB);            
    }
```

And for 1st screen i am not able to get any idea..

Any help please.

Comment: Not exactly sure of the error but have you tried printing the value of `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath` on the new machine?

Comment: uh, you should probably use something like `string reportPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetDirectory(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)), "VisitorIDReport.rpt");`

You should never build a path 'manually'. Especially not by hardcoding backslashes.

Comment: oh, also about the login box: From my experience that box pops up as soon as CrystalReports misses at least one parameter for a report.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler i tried your code but it gives me "IDENTIFIED EXPECTED" for reportpath and also can you kindly tell me what parameter i am missing ?

Comment: oh, had one closing bracket too much. Just remove the second one behind Location. Given the exception, probably all parameters and/or the document path.

Comment: @SteffenWinkler Yes.Thanks. i tried as you said..atleast i got a diff exception now stating that "Load Report Failed"..Any Guess ?? Also share me any examples for parameters..i am searching but not finding any same/relevant answers.. thanks once again for investing your time

Comment: by parameters I meant the values inside the ReportSource. Since those are used as Parameters inside the report.

No clue about the second problem. You should probably create another question for that. I'll post my comment as an answer.

Comment: @Steffen i have adding the report file manually while creating setup. Is it right ?? y should i combine when the crystal report is there inside the  folder.. plz clarify

Comment: i tried your new answer but still getting the same error

Comment: @kumartyr what problem are you talking about? The problem in your question is about an (apparently) incorrect file path. That problem should've been solved by my comment above/my answer. If you're facing a different problem now you should create another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the directory that contains the current program, it's better to do something like this:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectory(System.Reflection.Assembly.Ge‌​tExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Since you've a file inside that directory that you want to load, a much cleaner/more readable approach would be something like this:

```
string directoryContainingTheExecutable = System.IO.Path.GetDirectory(System.Reflection.Assembly.Ge‌​tExecutingAssembly().Location);
string reportPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(directoryContainingTheExecutable, "VisitorIDReport.rpt");
```

The Combine function makes sure that the path is correctly assembled. Meaning you don't have to worry about something like C:\Program Files\MyProgram\MyFile.rpt. Or, in case your program is used in a Linux environment, you won't have to replace all backslashes with forwardslashes.